# SharePoint add-in upgrade error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to upgrade the SharePoint add-in, from Version: 1.0.1.35 to Version: 1.0.1.36 in site contents, but i am getting this error:

> Sorry weren't able to update your app. We are going back to the
>   previous version.

Here is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

When i go into the detail section of the app, i see the error as follows:

[image]

What could be the possible reason for this issue? As i have hardly made a little change from the previous version to this version.

Comment: did you try retracting the app and adding it again?

Comment: As i have added it from app catalog, so i can not extract it, of course i can remove the app from site collection, but that will result in loss of configured data, that i can not do.